# Force height and scrollbar in Ext.tip (Extjs 3.4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs3

I have an Ext.tip component:

```
var tip = new Ext.Tip({
    header: true,
    collapsible: true,
    width: 350
});
```

and it receives results from queries. Sometimes it gets small paragraphs and sometimes big ones. It resizes just nicely based on their sizes. I would like, though, to set a specific tip's height and get a scrollbar if needed. For that I've tried:

```
autoScroll: true,
overflow: 'auto',
layout: 'fit',
height: 300,
```

but they had no effect on what I want. Checking http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Tip suggested me that there is no way as far as I understand. Is there a way in ExtJS 3.4 to achieve this? a dirty-hack solution perhaps?

A simple minimal working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gery/m7xdxwp8/8/

Any hints are appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the source code, I saw that there are a couple of flags that can be changed that will allow your Ext.Tip instance to be scrollable and have a fixed height:

```
var tip = new Ext.Tip({
    header: true,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    width: 350,
    height: 50,
    autoScroll: true
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/gportela/deojvevn/

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: holy macaroni, pretty amazing your answer, thanks, but since I'm not an expert in extjs it seems that it's not an easy approach to take, it's nice because of the challenge to learn, though. I think I can get a simple minimal working example in jsfiddle and will share it here, I'd appreciate your further inputs on it in order to get the scrollbar+height in Ext.Tip working properly.

Comment: Sure, but also consider updating your application to ExtJS 5 or 6. It's pretty rare to see people with ExtJS 3 knowledge these days.

Comment: yeah that's true, but moving away from 3.4 right now is very difficult for several reasons, but especially because of time to rewrite things again.

Comment: I understand, let me know when you share your fiddle example. Use https://fiddle.sencha.com if possible.

Comment: please check my simple minimal working example, I put it also in my original post above: http://jsfiddle.net/Gery/m7xdxwp8/8/

Comment: Has someone ever told you that you are a total genius? thanks!! it works like a champ, cool!! it'd be cool to know how you got the right combination, thanks again!

Comment: When I was reading the source (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Tip.html#Ext-Tip) I noticed that Ext.Tip extends the panel but sets `autoHeight: true` in the prototype.  After changing that it was only a matter of setting autoScroll to true as well. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Try aligning it to: 'bl-bl',[10,-10],

Comment: I guess we are transforming the comments session here in a chat room. You should create another question for this problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about use in Ext 3.4 but i made an example how it works in Ext 4.2 with QuickTips: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o13

QuickTips are part of ExtJS since 2.3

Hope it helps

--- EDIT ---

Made an example with 3.4 and QuickTips: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/u7e

Comment: thanks for that, nice example, I'm going to try it in my code and let you know.

Comment: After some attempts with your suggestion, I couldn't get Ext.QuickTip working, it seems that it doesn't respond in the same way Ext.Tip works, why would it be so difficult to put a scrollbar to an Ext.Tip?

Comment: See the edit in my answer. I've tried normal Tips but ended up using QuickTips with a div and scrollbars. Ext 3.4 doesn't have that many options to achieve a special result. It's much easier in later versions.

Comment: thanks a lot! that's nice, I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid off this hover effect and simply get the tip with the scrollbar? it's true, but very difficult to move away from 3.4 right now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give a try with the style propertie?
Something like:

> style:"overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;",

or

> style:"overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x: scroll;",

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the scrollbar didn't appear with it.